# Bandwidth monitoring on Cisco 3750 switch

Tags: bandwidth

I have 2 x Real-time video streaming device(With Gigabit Ethernet) with me which are connected to a Cisco 3750 Catalyst switch.

Can anyone share the process of knowing the real-time traffic exchange between the ports?

I have not tried SPAN yet, not sure if that will give the desired result.

I need to know how much bandwidth is being used by the video streaming device (Input & Output).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for SNMP. (Simple network management protocol) it will allow you to view bandwidth on a port by port basis. I personally use "solarwinds" tools. But a quick search for free SNMP should bring up plenty of options.

These instructions should get you going:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3750scg/swsnmp.html

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the response. I'll check with SNMP and share the outcome here.

Comment: It should be suitable for your needs. The only downside is software on a computer must be running to capture the data for the SNMP info. I believe the catalyst series switches also have a button on the front of the switch. One of the modes will show you the maximum transfer rate across the switch backplane since the switch was booted. You could reboot the switch and get a guestimate using that method.

Comment: Cheers brother. will check and update.

Many thanks

Comment: did this work out for you?

Comment: Hey Tim,
Sorry for the delay in response. I actually checked the basic bandwidth usage using the below command in the sub config mode 
" int gi portnumber"
I understand this is not giving the real-time traffic but that worked for me to check the maximum bandwidth on the port
Thank you for you help.
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup a mirroring port(SPAN) and use wireshark or other programs to monitor. Here is a guide for you:

http://blog.wfilterros.com/?p=417